# Reverse SSH tunnel connection refused

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect to a server behind NAT so I can ssh into the `dev-server` from the `remote-server`.

I have set up a reverse ssh tunnel from the `dev-server` to the `remote-server` as follows, in order to piggyback on the  connection `dev-server->remote-server`:

```
ssh -R 8022:localhost:22 remote-server
```

`remote-server` refers to the following .ssh/config entry on the `dev-server`

```
  41 Host remote-server
  42   Hostname [some-ip]
  43   User [some-user]
  44   Port 22
```

which allows me to ssh into the remote-server, as in `ssh remote-server` from the `dev-server`.

The sshd_config file of the `remote-server` contains the following lines:

```
31 AllowTcpForwarding yes
32 GatewayPorts yes
```

which I read is required.

The connection is established on the `remote-server` as shown in:

```
    sudo lsof -i -n | egrep '\<sshd\>' | grep -v ":ssh"
sshd      32724       fxp-trust    9u  IPv4  63530      0t0  TCP *:8022 (LISTEN)
sshd      32724       fxp-trust   10u  IPv6  63531      0t0  TCP *:8022 (LISTEN)
```

The `dev-server` has the `remote-server` pub key installed.

The firewall on the `remote-server` has the following rules:

```
sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active    
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] OpenSSH                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] Nginx Full                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 8022                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 4] OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 5] Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 6] 8022 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

To connect from the `remote-server` to the `dev-server` I did:

`ssh -p8022 localhost`

with the response:

```
    ssh -p8022 localhost -v
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/[remote-server]/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 8022.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/[remote-server]/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/[remote-server]/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/[remote-server]/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/[remote-server]/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/[remote-server]/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/[remote-server]/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/[remote-server]/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/[remote-server]/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I don't know why.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The lsof output shows sshd listening on 5022, not 8022...?

Comment: @willyab so is it fine now then? by the way ssh has a server log often more useful than the client logging.

Comment: No, it's not fine, I was testing several approaches and just pasted the wrong line.